# Writing a Tuple2Serializer for json4s

Tags: scala, json4s

I am having trouble turning my data into nested JSON objects. My current data looks like this:

```
Map(23 -> {"errorCode":null,"runStatusId":null,"lakeHdfsPath":"/user/jmblnvr/20140817_011500_zoot_kohls_offer_init.dat","fieldIndex":23,"datasetFieldName":"TERM_MM","datasetFieldSum":0.0,"datasetFieldMin":0.0,"datasetFieldMax":0.0,"datasetFieldMean":0.0,"datasetFieldSigma":0.0,"datasetFieldNullCount":170544.0,"datasetFieldObsCount":0.0,"datasetFieldKurtosis":0.0,"datasetFieldSkewness":0.0,"frequencyDistribution":null,"id":null,"fieldType":"NUMBER"}, 32 -> {"errorCode":null,"runStatusId":null,"lakeHdfsPath":"/user/jmblnvr/20140817_011500_zoot_kohls_offer_init.dat","fieldIndex":32,"datasetFieldName":"ACCT_NBR","datasetFieldSum":0.0,"datasetFieldMin":0.0,"datasetFieldMax":0.0,"datasetFieldMean":0.0,"datasetFieldSigma":0.0,"datasetFieldNullCount":0.0,"datasetFieldObsCount":0.0,"datasetFieldKurtosis":0.0,"datasetFieldSkewness":0.0,"frequencyDistribution":"(6393050780099594,56810)","id":null,"fieldType":"STRING"} etc. etc.
```

When I run it through:

```
  def jsonClob(json: scala.collection.mutable.Map[Int, String]): String = {
   implicit val formats = org.json4s.DefaultFormats
    val A = Serialization.write(json)
    A
  }
```

I get the following Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" scala.MatchError: (23,{"errorCode":null,"fieldIndex":23,"datasetFieldObsCount":0.0,"datasetFieldKurtosis":0.0,"datasetFieldSkewness":0.0,"frequencyDistribution":null,"runStatusId":null,"lakeHdfsPath":"/user/jmblnvr/20140817_011500_zoot_kohls_offer_init.dat","datasetFieldName":"TERM_MM","datasetFieldSum":0.0,"datasetFieldMin":0.0,"datasetFieldMax":0.0,"datasetFieldMean":0.0,"datasetFieldSigma":0.0,"datasetFieldNullCount":170544.0,"id":null,"fieldType":"NUMBER"}) (of class scala.Tuple2)
    at org.json4s.Extraction$.internalDecomposeWithBuilder(Extraction.scala:132)
    at org.json4s.Extraction$.decomposeWithBuilder(Extraction.scala:67)
    at org.json4s.Extraction$.decompose(Extraction.scala:194)
    at org.json4s.jackson.Serialization$.write(Serialization.scala:22)
    at com.capitalone.dts.toolset.jsonWrite$.jsonClob(jsonWrite.scala:17)
    at com.capitalone.dts.dq.profiling.DQProfilingEngine.profile(DQProfilingEngine.scala:264)
    at com.capitalone.dts.dq.profiling.Profiler$.main(DQProfilingEngine.scala:64)
    at com.capitalone.dts.dq.profiling.Profiler.main(DQProfilingEngine.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:569)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:166)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:189)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

I am taking advice from another post I created but am having 0 luck with a custom serializer. So far my code looks like this but completely lost on it:

```
class Tuple2Serializer extends CustomSerializer[(Int, String)](   format => (
  {
    case JObject(JField(JInt(k), v)) => (k, v)
  },
  {
    case (t: Int, s:String ) => (t -> s)
  }   ) )
```

Edit:
I have it working now thanks to the comment but it is creating with these \, not sure why or how to remove without ruining the JSON

Example:

```
\"errorCode\":null,\"runStatusId\":null,\"lakeHdfsPath\":\"/user/jmblnvr/20140817_011500_zoot_kohls_offer_init.dat\",\"fieldIndex\":45,\"datasetFieldName\":\"PRESENTABLE_FLAG\"
```

Comment: I think your problem is that the serializer wants the keys in map to be strings. Try `Serialization.write(json.map { case (k,v) => (k.toString -> v) })`

Comment: Great, one question when I write in existing JSON to be converted it now add's a weird back slash: {"45":"{\"errorCode\":null,\"fieldIndex\":45,\"runStatusId\":null,\"lakeHdfsPath\":\"/user/jmblnvr/20140817_011500_zoot_kohls_offer_init.dat\",\"datasetFieldName\":\"PRESENTABLE_FLAG\",\"datasetFieldSum\"